# Export exploded objects from blender to unity

Tags: export, import, unity

For a research project on object recognition, we used objects in blender and distorted them with the quick explosion effect. The explosion effect in blender works nicely. However, we need to import the objects in unity. Now it seems like a lot of the particles of the exploded objects are missing, after importing them to unity. Do you have any advice on how to fix this issue, and make the exploded objects in unity look like the objects originally created in blender? I attached an example to see the difference between blender and unity.

Any help is very much appreciated!
Best,
Anton

[image: object in blender][image: object in unity]

Answer (score 0):

Fbx (default) format can't handle this. It doesn't support modifiers except armature. It seems export such objects is relatively similar to export cloth animations, so you can try some workarounds described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994103/how-to-import-cloth-simulation-from-blender-to-unity

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! Unfortunately, this did not work out, as we do not need the whole animation. It's basically one single frame of the animation, in which the explosion effect is sufficient to distort the object.

Comment: Ah, ok, then just apply the modifier at this frame - Ctrl+A-> apply modifiers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try MeshSync with Unity and Blender. It is based on different kind of data, it works with all the Blender's modifiers I tried until now. It will generate a cache file that Unity could read once the addon is install both in Blender and Unity, and you'll be able to see exactly what you have in Blender inside Unity. Bonus : You can save it as an animation in Unity ;)